# Extract data from Python locally html files

Tags: python, html

I would like to extract data from several html files in a folder (saved locally) and save the information to a text file. Most html toolboxes in Python seems to deal with online webpages and not locally saved files. For example, if I would like to find the "CAS registry number" from all files and write those to a text file how should I do?

Example of a html row containg the informtion:

```
<DIV class=detailTitle><SPAN class=title>CAS Registry Number</SPAN> 555-34-0</DIV>
```

Comment: Why would you think there's any difference between a local HTML file and a remote one? Contrary to your assertion, most "html toolboxes" (I presume you mean parsing libraries) don't even mention where you get the HTML, just how to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use PyQuery, which is very elegant for handling the html elements'

tutorial is [here](http://pyquery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

code as :

```
from pyquery import PyQuery

html = open("index.html", 'r').read() # local html

query = pyquery(html)

query("li").eq(1).text()
......
```

Comment: should be "query = PyQuery(html)" in line 3

Answer (score -1):

The simplest method would be using BeautifulSoup

1. Read the file containing the html

```
a = open('file.html').read()
```

2. Parse the html using BeautifulSoup:

```
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
    bs = BeautifulSoup(a)
    //process the file as in normal cases
```

Comment: Please don't recommend parsing HTML with regex.

Comment: Removed regex. I suggested that only because he wanted that small piece of info to be extracted, which was very easy with regex.